# Stop Concatenating HTML hrefs to address bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `btn-group` with some buttons, each of which will lead to a different page. The `btn-group` will be visible on every page.

Here is the html for the `btn-group`,

```
        <div class="btn-group-lg text-center" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="" role="button">Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_schedule/" role="button">Schedule</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_syllabus/" role="button">Syllabus</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_records/" role="button">Records</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_achievements/" role="button">Achievements</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_gallery/" role="button">Gallery</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="view_contact/" role="button">Contact</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="about/" role="button">About Us</a>

        </div>
```

But whenever I press a button, it modifies the URL in the address bar.
Example:- From http://127.0.0.1:8000/shotokankaratebd/, if I press the Schedule button, it changes the URL to http://127.0.0.1:8000/shotokankaratebd/view_schedule.

After that, if I press the schedule button again, it changes it to http://127.0.0.1:8000/shotokankaratebd/view_schedule/view_schedule which is an invalid URL and I get an error.

How can I write it so that whenever a button is pressed, only the part after http://127.0.0.1:8000/shotokankaratebd/ is affected?

EDITED to include the new hrefs:

```
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/" role="button">Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_schedule/" role="button">Schedule</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_syllabus/" role="button">Syllabus</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_records/" role="button">Records</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_achievements/" role="button">Achievements</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_gallery/" role="button">Gallery</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/view_contact/" role="button">Contact</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="../shotokankaratebd/about/" role="button">About Us</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried `../`?

Comment: I just tried. But the same problem persists if I press anything other than the Home button. I have edited the question to include the new hrefs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
All I needed to do was start my hrefs with / which would reset the url back to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ after every button click.

HTML buttons are as follows:

```
        <div class="btn-group-lg text-center" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">

            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/" role="button">Home</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_schedule/" role="button">Schedule</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_syllabus/" role="button">Syllabus</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_records/" role="button">Records</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_achievements/" role="button">Achievements</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_gallery/" role="button">Gallery</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_contact/" role="button">Contact</a>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/about/" role="button">About Us</a>

        </div>
```

Comment: Your answer is still the wrong way to go about it in Django. The answers above are the correct way to include urls in templates!

Answer (score 1):

You should not hard code your urls. Use [django's url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to fetch urls for your views.

Answer (score 1):

If your urls are leading to another view or another app's view, you should use django feature of using dynamic urls.

For example if you have a view `view_schedule`, you should give it a name in urls.py like

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('shotokankaratebd/view_schedule/', views.name_of_your_view, name=view_schedule),
...
]
```

and whenever and whichever template if you want to access this view you can just type

template.html

```
<a href="{% url 'view_schedule' %}"><button>Schedule</button></a>
```

instead of

```
 class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="/shotokankaratebd/view_schedule/" role="button">Schedule</a>
```

Hard Coding it like that.

Comment: <a href="{% url 'view_schedule' %}"><button>Schedule</button></a>

Does view_schedule here refer to the argument of name in path()? Or does it refer to the name of the view function itself?

Comment: It refers to the name which you give in urls.py and not the view(function).